# Event registration on a Rhino Mock strict mock

Tags: events, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to setup a strictmock using Rhino Mocks 3.6 where there is some event registration expected. How do I setup the expectancies of registration? This is what i have (and does not work)

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var publisher = mocks.StrictMock<IPublisher>();
using (mocks.Record())
{
   publisher.Changed += null;
   LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
}        
using (mocks.PlayBack())
{
   publisher.Changed += SomeEventHandler();
}
```

I get the error message like this

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : IPublisher.add_Changed(...); Expected #0, Actual #1.
```

What is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: Is "Changed" virtual?  And could we see the IPublisher interface definition?

Comment: Actually it is working just fine like this. I had another problem with another mocks that led me to think this was not the way. I'll leave the question for future reference. I cant answer it because I am a 'new' user

Comment: You can answer it now :)